# How to export rxjs Subject with pre-defined pipe operators?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to export rxjs Subject with some pre-defined behavior (via `pipe()`).

e.g. I want to export a subject that do `console.log` on each new value:

```
export const subj$ = new Subject()
  .pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('updated')
  )
```

This works, and I'm able to `subscribe()` to `subj$`.

The problem is that this way it's impossible to do `subj$.next('foo')`.

Of course I can export two variables for `subscribe()` and for `next()`, but that's supper silly

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot do this. Because `pipe` converts `Subject` to `Observable` and this record is similar to this: `new Subject().asObservable()`.

But, you can create your own `Subject`, for example from source (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts). And make any function to invoke inside.